# Decorating All RESTEasy Reactive Request Handling in Quarkus Amazon Lambda HTTP Extension

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

I would like to decorate all HTTP request handling in my Quarkus RESTEasy Reactive application that is deployed on AWS Lambda.

The [Quarkus Amazon Lambda HTTP](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda-http) extension helps users serve their RESTEasy Reactive routes on AWS Lambda via the AWS API Gateway integration. RESTEasy Reactive allows users to decorate request handling using a standard [ContainerResponseFilter](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.4.Final/userguide/html/ch35.html). However, the response filter is not invoked in the case where the resource throws an exception. In my use case, I need to know when the request has completed, even if it has completed with an error.

If one were deploying RESTEasy Reactive on a servlet container, then one could use a servlet filter to decorate all reqeusts handled by RESTEasy. But, in a deployment that uses the Quarkus Amazon Lambda HTTP extension, how might one decorate all request handling?

Comment: Are you sure the `ContainerResponseFilter` is not invoked when an exception is thrown?

Comment: @geoand it's true. `ContainerResponseFilter` is not invoked when an "unmapped" exception was thrown. When the exception mapped to response by an `ExceptionMapper` the filter will active, othervise it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Jakarta Restful Webservices startard defines *filters* and *interceptors* to handle even modify incoming requests or outgoing responses and the ExceptionMapper interface to catch and map exceptions to proper `Response` object.

Unfortunately neither `ContainerResponseFilter` nor `WriterInterceptor` not invoked when the thrown expception was not mapped by an `ExceptionMapper`

Luckily RestEasy Reactive extension gives a very good point to intercept all requests and responses.

The sample REST endpoint is:

```java
@Path("/api")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        Log.info("Executing resource method");
        return "Hello from RESTEasy Reactive";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/mapped")
    public String mapped(@NotBlank @QueryParam("param") String param) {
        Log.info("Executing resource method");
        return "Hello " + param + "!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/unmapped")
    public String error(@QueryParam("param") String param) {
        Log.info("Executing resource method");
        if (null == param) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Param problem");
        }
        return "Hello " + param + "!";
    }

    @DELETE
    public void noContent() {
        Log.info("Executing resource method");
    }
}
```

The `hello` method just returns an 200-OK response with a static response body.
The second method called `mapped` accepts a query parameter. This parameter is validated by Hibernate Validator. An invalid input (a blank or missing parameter) will throw an exception which is mapped by [ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/hibernate-validator/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/validator/runtime/jaxrs/ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper.java)
The `unmapped` method throws an `IllegalArgumentExpceiton` but there is not built-in `ExceptionMapper` to handle that.
Finally, a special case. The `noContent` method will return 204-No Content, so there is not any response body.

There are two other provider:

```java
@Provider
public class SampleResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("X-ResponseFilter", "accepted");

    }
}
```

and

```java
@Provider
public class SampleWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        context.getHeaders().add("X-Interceptor", "intercepted");
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Calling hello (`/api` endpoint) both provider invoked

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  http://localhost:8080/api

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< X-Interceptor: intercepted
< X-ResponseFilter: accepted
< content-length: 28
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Calling `/mapped` endpoint: both provider invoked because the prevously mentioned `ExceptionMapper` caught that exception and mapped to a `Response` object.

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  http://localhost:8080/api/mapped

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/mapped HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< validation-exception: true
< X-Interceptor: intercepted
< X-ResponseFilter: accepted
< content-length: 131
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Calling `/unmapped` none of the registered providers invoked.

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  http://localhost:8080/api/unmapped
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/unmapped HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 1337
< 
response body omitted for brevity
```

Calling `/api` with `DELETE` HTTP method only `SampleResponseFilter` invoked, because no response body was served.

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/silent
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> DELETE /api/silent HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< X-ResponseFilter: accepted
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Resteasy Reactive allows to register custom interceptors. These interceptors will be invoked on every requests and responses.

A sample interceptor is:

```java
import io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.filters.Filters;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleRouteFilter {

    void responseFilter(@Observes Filters filters) {
        filters.register(rc -> {
            rc.response().putHeader("X-RouteFilter", "filtered");
            rc.next();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

From now every response will contain `X-RouteFilter` header key even if that response is handled successfully or not, handled by some rest endpoint or not (e.g. Not Found or Method Not Allowed).

For example:

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  http://localhost:8080/api/unmapped
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/unmapped HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< X-RouteFilter: filtered
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 1337
<
```

or:

```
spinner@bistromath:~$ curl -v  -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/unmapped
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> DELETE /api/unmapped HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> UserOb-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< X-RouteFilter: filtered
< X-ResponseFilter: accepted
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**NOTE**: That reactive filter registered to all requests and responses. Registered to `/q/dev-ui` or `/q/health`, etc. So be careful before modifing anything.

#### UPDATE - add custom Vert.x handler

By observing the `Filters` event is allowed to register custom Vert.x handler. To modify headers **after** the actual resource mehtod was executed this filter could be a good starting point:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleRouteFilter {

    void responseFilter(@Observes Filters filters) {
        filters.register(rc -> {
            Log.info("Before rc.next()");
            rc.addHeadersEndHandler(event -> {
                Log.info("Handling HeadersEnd with status: " + rc.response().getStatusCode());
                rc.response().putHeader("X-HeadersEnd", "HeadersEnd - " + rc.response().getStatusCode());
            });
            rc.response().putHeader("X-RouteFilter", "filtered");
            rc.next();
            Log.info("After rc.next()");
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Calling a rest endpoint the application log will contain something like this:

```
2023-08-07 18:21:21,298 INFO  [io.git.zfo.SampleRouteFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Before rc.next()
2023-08-07 18:21:21,299 INFO  [io.git.zfo.SampleRouteFilter] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) After rc.next()
2023-08-07 18:21:21,299 INFO  [io.git.zfo.ExampleResource] (executor-thread-1) Executing resource method
2023-08-07 18:21:21,299 INFO  [io.git.zfo.SampleRouteFilter] (executor-thread-1) Handling HeadersEnd with status: 204
```

To choose the best phase (headersEnd, bodyEnd, end) to attach just read the [javadoc of RoutingContext](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html).

Comment: Thank you. This solution likely solves most use cases, but it does not allow me to decorate the RESTEasy Reactive handler. The application's RESTEasy resources are executed after the filter, regardless of the priority I assign. I would expect a filter with priority 0 to execute the resources during the `rc.next()` call.

I need the filter's logic to execute _after_ the RESTEasy Reactive resources have executed. Do you know of a way to decorate the RESTEasy reactive route handler?

Comment: @jdgilday I've just updated the answer to demonstrate how to register a handler.